# Are Primitives in Javascript (eg. 3) Technically Considered Expressions?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I know that, for instance, `1 + 2` is an expression ... an expression that returns `3`.  Since an expression basically means a thing that returns a value, and `3` returns the value `3`, it would seem like `3` itself would also be an expression.

However, I've never seen any examples of expressions that were simply primitive values, so I'm curious: is `3`, or for that matter `'foo'`, technically considered to be  an expression?

Comment: Yes. A plain number is an expression, `"hello world"` is an expression; `false` is an expression.

Comment: Think about it: the syntax for an array index is obviously an expression in square brackets, and `foo[4]` clearly works fine.

Comment: Not only what @Pointy already said, but if you add a semicolon to it, your expression becomes a statement: `3;`. Have a look at Marijn Haverbeke's book: https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_5fUOQZwwHx

Comment: In the world of AST's, it's also an expression ->  `"type": "ExpressionStatement"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are expressions by themselves, **operators and assignments are both
optional.**

## Expressions

> An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.

Conceptually we can consider two types of expressions:

- With **Assignment** (side effects) : Assign value to a variable. Eg: `x=23`
- With **Evaluation** : Those that evaluate and therefore resolve to a value. Eg: `6*6`

JavaScript has the following expression categories:

- **Arithmetic**: Evaluate to a number. eg. `5.2534`. (Generally arithmetic operators are used)
- **String**: Evaluates to a character string, for example, `"Foo"` or `"123"`. (Generally string operators are used)
- **Logical**: Evaluates to `true` or `false`. ( Generally logical operators are used)
- **Left-hand-side expressions**: Left values are the destination of an assignment. eg. `new` or  `super`
- **Primary expressions**: Basic keywords  and general expressions in JS. eg. `this`

---

Based on Mozilla Developer Documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Antlr ECMAScript grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/ecmascript/JavaScript/ECMAScript.g4), an `expressionStatement` is composed of `expressionSequence`, which is composed of `singleExpression`, which can be a `literal`. Here are the relevant parts:

```
expressionStatement
 : expressionSequence
 ;

expressionSequence
 : singleExpression ( ',' singleExpression )*
 ;

singleExpression
 : Function Identifier? '(' formalParameterList? ')' '{' functionBody '}' # FunctionExpression
 ... # Cut for brevity
 | literal                                                                # LiteralExpression
 | arrayLiteral                                                           # ArrayLiteralExpression
 | objectLiteral                                                          # ObjectLiteralExpression
 | '(' expressionSequence ')'                                             # ParenthesizedExpression
 ;

literal
 : ( NullLiteral 
   | BooleanLiteral
   | StringLiteral
   | RegularExpressionLiteral
   )
 | numericLiteral
 ;
```

> However, I've never seen any examples of expressions that were simply primitive values

That depends on what you think an expression is.